# Preserving a Configured Guest User Profile

Tags: guest-account

I am configuring my school's macs to have a specially configured Guest User so that when students log in as Guest, they have Chrome all set up, with a pre-configured BlockSite chrome extension, and several bookmarks, and open tabs, etc.

The way I have done this is to log in as guest, install the browser extension, configure it and the browser in general, pre-open tabs, save chrome preferences, etc., and then I copy
 - /Users/Guest/Library to
 - /System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Library

This works great until I copy that same folder to a USB drive, and then copy the Library folder from the USB drive to the next macbook that needs to have a pre-configured Guest User.  Once I have it copied over and log in as Guest, there are a couple things wrong:

1. The browser extension is no longer installed
2. Chrome's preferences are gone

I am sure there are others, but those are the two big ones.  So my question is, if I am copying the Library folder in its entirety, why are these things not carrying over?  What do I need to be doing differently?